# rsync on Linux absolute paths in quotes interpretted as relative

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm trying to sync two local directories with rsync using the following command:

rsync -azvv --delete '/path/to/dir1' '/path/with space/to/dir2'

The paths are absolute. If neither of the paths contains spaces, I can omit the quotes, and it works fine. However, when the paths are wrapped in quotes, rsync interprets them as relative to the working directory, and so looks for /home/rob//path/to/dir1 and /home/rob//path/with space/to/dir2

Any idea what is causing this?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than quoting the paths, maybe you should try escaping your spaces

Comment: Or you could try `rsync --no-R ...`. It turns off relative paths.

Comment: @TimZimmermann The --no-relative option doesn't appear to do anything.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an unix command. Try asking on unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: em... what tells you the interpretation of relative path? the args are parsed by bash, so rsync itself shouldn't get involved.